# Arch linux startup application (script)

Tags: boot, archlinux

I want to use an RPi running Arch Linux to power an embedded device and I therefore need the RPi to launch a (Mono C#) application the moment after it has finished booting without the user having to do anything. I have seen tutorials of how to do this on Raspbian but not for Arch. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred way to do this on Archlinux is to use `systemd`.

> systemd is the default init framework, replacing initscripts. The
>   services which are started by systemd can be found in the subfolders
>   of /etc/systemd/system/. Services can be enabled using the systemctl
>   command. For more information about systemd and how to write autostart
>   scripts for it, see at systemd.

Create a new file in `/etc/systemd/system` (e.g. `myscript.service`) and add the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run the following commands :

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/myscript
systemctl enable myscript.service
```

This example assumes you want your script to start up when the target multi-user is launched.

Note: In case you ever want to start a shell script, make sure you have `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of the script.

More info: [Autostarting with Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting), [Systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd)